# Removing whitespaces in a txt line and adding the values to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following line of text from a .txt file

```
  0.14999999999999999       0.20000000000000001       0.29999999999999999       0.34999999999999998       0.50000000000000000       0.59999999999999998       0.69999999999999996       0.72999999999999998       0.84999999999999998       0.90000000000000002     \n
```

I've been facing a problem on how to make this first line into a list. I've tried line.strip() but that only took care of the first and last spaces. There are still spaces left that I couldn't get rid of. As seen below:

```
'0.14999999999999999       0.20000000000000001       0.29999999999999999       0.34999999999999998       0.50000000000000000       0.59999999999999998       0.69999999999999996       0.72999999999999998       0.84999999999999998       0.90000000000000002'
```

I also can't just replace all " " with "" as all numbers would get crumpled together. I also can't assume the number of whitespaces, nor the number of spaces before the ".", as I may have numbers greater than or equal to 10 down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.split`.

Here is example.

```
a = '0.14999999999999999       0.20000000000000001       0.29999999999999999       0.34999999999999998       0.50000000000000000       0.59999999999999998       0.69999999999999996       0.72999999999999998       0.84999999999999998       0.90000000000000002'

import re
output = re.split(' +', a)
```

the output is

```
['0.14999999999999999',
 '0.20000000000000001',
 '0.29999999999999999',
 '0.34999999999999998',
 '0.50000000000000000',
 '0.59999999999999998',
 '0.69999999999999996',
 '0.72999999999999998',
 '0.84999999999999998',
 '0.90000000000000002'].
```

If you want every element in the output becomes float, then use `map`.

```
output = list(map(float, output))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `re`. Just use `split` on the line.

```py
' 1 2  3   4    5 '.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```